# pacat -p some file in backup-skript needs $DISPLAY for X11 why?

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, backup, rsync

I wrote an udev-rule and a systemd-unit, so if I plugin a particular harddrive rsync backups my /home in background and play a audio file when ready.

During my first attempt I get following error `pulseaudio[8802]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11`

Note this I have fixed. I got my sound back after skript is ready.

But I don't understand why pacat or even aplay needs this variable for playing only audio. I'm runnning ubuntu bionic with xfce4-session.

Comment: *Why*  is always going to be opinion-based (so not posting an answer), but these are userland programs so the programmer assumes the user is going to run them in userland and is going to use `dbus` instead of calling kernel functions.  No one ever suspected their program was going to be run without a user session...  **;-)**

Comment: this makes sense to me and explains the throwing dbus error. Please make an answer and I except it.

Comment: Favour returned!  Question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `aplay` and `pacat` are userland programs, so the easiest way *for the programmer* to get the sound out there is to use the `dbus` library as no one in their right mind is going to use these in `cron`, or in a `udev` rule, or *heaven forbid* in `systemd`, right???  **:-)**

Well, they were right until you came along, and you indeed took the correct solution to solve this issue.

If you would like to be able to make a sound without X running at all (E.G. a headless server), you might echo the `ASCII` `BEL`¹ character to a `tty`.

<sub>**Note 1:** [007: really retro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#/media/File:USASCII_code_chart.png): a beep was more important then a Line Feed (10), Form Feed (12) or Carriage Return (13)...</sub>